# HtmlResponse wrong encoding

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I can't find any elements I'm searching for in response and I think it's caused by wrong charset in HtmlResponse.

So, here I have a response described

```
new_response = HtmlResponse(response.url, body=response.body)
```

And `new_response.text` for this response looks like

> bÃ]Ð$Ð♣MÃF<ÀÉ4?Ó³

When I open this page in browser I can see there are two different charset described in http response header and html meta tag - iso-8859-1 and utf-8.

So what should I do to get this content with valid charset?

Comment: can you share the url?